# Big-O complexity of nested for loops

Tags: big-o, nested-loops

I'm confused about the complexity of the following (the operation performed inside the inner loop is in constant time):

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  for(int j=i; j<n; j++)
```

is this O(n^2) or O(n)?  I figure O(n^2).  Any ideas?

also the following makes me curious:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
   for(j=0; j<i; j++)
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely `O(n squared)`, of course.  Summary explanation for both cases: 1 + 2 + ... + n is `n(n+1)/2`, that is, `(n squared plus n) / 2` (and in big-O we drop the second, lesser part, so we're left with n squared / 2 which is of course `O(n squared)`).

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, those nested loops are still O(n^2). The actual number of operations is something close to (n^2)/2, which, after discarding the constant 1/2 factor, is O(n^2).